# How to detect if a file on Windows is marked for Offline caching

Tags: c#, .net, windows, caching, networking

Is it possible to programmatically detect if a certain file/folder is a local copy cached by the [Windows Offline Folders](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/understanding-offline-files#1TC=windows-7) mechanism?

Is it possible to detect if a certain file/folder marked to be used as an offline file/folder?

I'm asking this question because I've had some issue with one of our software.
 This software use an Access mdb file, the MDB file reside on a network share, and this network share has been marked to be used offline.
Clearly this is a recipe for disaster, because offline folder cache mechanism can't sync the contents of an access mdb file that is simultaneously used in 2 or more different computers.

So I would like to modify our software in a way to give a warning to the user when the DB is marked for offline use.